# Cordova : after java update not able to build android apps

Tags: android, cordova

I am getting below error after updating Java to 12.

```
C:\wamp64\www\mobileApp\abcApp>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 12.0.2
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Google not providing much resolution for it. failed to build even new project also.
My **environment Variables**:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Android development requires java 8. Apache cordova creates android projects, so you need java 8 for them to work.

I mean you have to downgrade your java version to 8, 12 is not supported.

Comment: I have java 12 already you can see the environment variable is set to 12.

Comment: You need java 8, not java 12, android development requires java 8.